# How do I extract messages from an unbounded queue every N seconds and spawn them on to a Tokio handler?

Tags: stream, rust, future, rust-tokio

I am trying to extract messages (which are futures themselves) from an unbounded queue every N seconds and spawn them into the Tokio handler.

I’ve tried dozens of variations but I cannot seem to find the right approach. It looks like it should be possible, but I always hit a future type mismatch or end up with borrow issues.

This is the code that shows more or less what I want:

```
let fut = Interval::new_interval(Duration::from_secs(1))
        .for_each(|num| vantage_dequeuer.into_future() )
        .for_each(|message:VantageMessage |{
            handle.spawn(message);
            return Ok(());
        })
        .map_err(|e| panic!("delay errored; err={:?}", e));

core.run(fut);
```

Complete code:

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.24
extern crate tokio; // 0.1.8
extern crate tokio_core; // 0.1.17

use futures::future::ok;
use futures::sync::mpsc;
use futures::{Future, Stream};
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::timer::Interval;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

type VantageMessage = Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + Send>;

fn main() {
    let (enqueuer, dequeuer) = mpsc::unbounded();
    let new_fut: VantageMessage = Box::new(ok(()).and_then(|_| {
        println!("Message!");
        return Ok(());
    }));
    enqueuer.unbounded_send(new_fut);
    let joinHandle = worker(Some(dequeuer));
    joinHandle.join();
}

/*
    Every second extract one message from dequeuer (or wait if not available)
    and spawn it in the core
*/
fn worker(
    mut vantage_dequeuer: Option<mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<VantageMessage>>,
) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    let dequeuer = dequeuer.take().unwrap();
    let joinHandle = thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
        let handle = core.handle();
        let fut = Interval::new_interval(Duration::from_secs(1))
            .for_each(|num| vantage_dequeuer.into_future())
            .for_each(|message: VantageMessage| {
                handle.spawn(message);
                return Ok(());
            })
            .map_err(|e| panic!("delay errored; err={:?}", e));

        core.run(fut);
        println!("Returned!");
    });
    return joinHandle;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=41968a9fb2194781202ca07497781589&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018)

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `dequeuer` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:33:20
   |
33 |     let dequeuer = dequeuer.take().unwrap();
   |                    ^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0599]: no method named `into_future` found for type `std::option::Option<futures::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::Future<Item=(), Error=()> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:38:46
   |
38 |             .for_each(|num| vantage_dequeuer.into_future())
   |                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `into_future` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&mut std::option::Option<futures::sync::mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<std::boxed::Box<(dyn futures::Future<Item=(), Error=()> + std::marker::Send + 'static)>>> : futures::Stream`
```

Comment: Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. For example, `dequeuer` is not a defined variable. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, and fields; `UpperCamelCase` for types; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants. Use `join_handle` instead, please. It's also not idiomatic to use `return` at the end of a block, just let the last line be an expression and thus the value of the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Interval` and `UnboundedReceiver` are both streams, so I'd use [`Stream::zip`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.24/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.zip) to combine them:

> The zipped stream waits for both streams to produce an item, and then returns that pair. If an error happens, then that error will be returned immediately. If either stream ends then the zipped stream will also end.

```
extern crate futures; // 0.1.24
extern crate tokio;   // 0.1.8
extern crate tokio_core; // 0.1.17

use futures::{
    future::ok,
    sync::mpsc,
    {Future, Stream},
};
use std::{thread, time::Duration};
use tokio::timer::Interval;
use tokio_core::reactor::Core;

type VantageMessage = Box<Future<Item = (), Error = ()> + Send>;

pub fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::unbounded();

    let new_fut: VantageMessage = Box::new(ok(()).and_then(|_| {
        println!("Message!");
        Ok(())
    }));
    tx.unbounded_send(new_fut).expect("Unable to send");
    drop(tx); // Close the sending side

    worker(rx).join().expect("Thread had a panic");
}

fn worker(queue: mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<VantageMessage>) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        let mut core = Core::new().unwrap();
        let handle = core.handle();

        core.run({
            Interval::new_interval(Duration::from_secs(1))
                .map_err(|e| panic!("delay errored; err={}", e))
                .zip(queue)
                .for_each(|(_, message)| {
                    handle.spawn(message);
                    Ok(())
                })
        })
        .expect("Unable to run reactor");
        println!("Returned!");
    })
}
```

Note that this doesn't actually *wait* for any of the spawned futures to complete before the reactor shuts down. If you want that, I'd switch to `tokio::run` and `tokio::spawn`:

```
fn worker(queue: mpsc::UnboundedReceiver<VantageMessage>) -> thread::JoinHandle<()> {
    thread::spawn(|| {
        tokio::run({
            Interval::new_interval(Duration::from_secs(1))
                .map_err(|e| panic!("delay errored; err={}", e))
                .zip(queue)
                .for_each(|(_, message)| {
                    tokio::spawn(message);
                    Ok(())
                })
        });
        println!("Returned!");
    })
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I looked into chain and was blind enough to not see zip. I want to shut down the reactor regardless of the side spawns finishing or not so core.run works better for me there.

Comment: if I am not wrong, for_each will end up in error when the streams complete, is there anyway to avoid the error? I want to be able to do core.run(future).expect("Errors in the pipeline"); and that would trigger always with for_each end_of_iteration behavior.

Comment: @ArkaitzJimenez *for_each will end up in error when the streams complete* — why do you say that? I haven't seen that. Are you able to provide code that makes that error?

Comment: well it looked like the error was an artifact of my previous impl, this works flawlessly.